# How to read/update values stored inside a map which is then inside of an array in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, google-cloud-firestore

To begin with I'm a newbie to Firestore and Android programming.

I have a collection which stores documents, each document contains an array of semesters, inside the semester array there will be an array of maps representing each semester. Inside the individual semester maps, there will be a number field identifying the semester and also another array called Students where it will contain an array of maps where each map will represent each student and store three different fields: ID of the student, DaysPresent, Total.

I'm trying to find a way to read the data for each individual student represented by ID in such a way where the semester number is taken into account.

For example, if the user selects Semester 1, it will go inside the array Semester and then load up the values from the first array which represents the Semester 1, and it will then display all the maps that represent each student where the days present and the total can be modified and read by the user.

One crucial key point is that the total number will always be the same for every individual map which means every individual student.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Mar 26th, 2020:

Actually it's possible using the solution in the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

---

If you intend to get a `List<Semester>` or a `List<Student>` when querying your Cloud Firestore database, please note that this is currently not possible. Even if those objects are of type `Semester` and `Student`, there is no way you can map them into a List of Semester/Student objects. To solve this, you need to write code to iterate those objects so you can convert them from a `List<Map>` to a `List<Semester>`and `List<Student>`. So you need to apply your own logic for that.

**Edit:**

The type of object that is returned when calling:

```
document.getData();
```

Is a `Map<String Object>`, so you need to iterate through the map according to your logic and get the data as needed.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the coding aspect of this? I'm a newbie and I'm in desperate need for some help regarding this issue.