# Failed to cast Object to POJO from Firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data structure like so: `Map<String, CustomPojo>` and I'm getting it from **Firestore** like so: `Map<String, Object>`. How can I get my custom map from this one, because I cannot cast it in any way.

My full code is trivial (from oficial docs page):

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                
               //this throws exception
               Map<String, CustomPojo> myCustomMap = (Map<String, CustomPojo>) map ;

               //even this throws exception
               for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                Object obj = entry.getValue();
                CustomPojo myObj= (CustomPojo)  obj;
               }

              //working darty solution
              for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String json = new Gson().toJson(entry.getValue());
                CustomPojo myObj= new Gson().fromJson(json, CustomPojo.class);
               }

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Here is data structure:

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo http://prntscr.com/ogtk0l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot cast it in any way.

This is because Firestore doesn't yet provide a way to do that. Please note that the following lines of code:

```
Object obj = entry.getValue();
CustomPojo myObj= (CustomPojo)  obj;
```

Will not work since `entry.getValue()` cannot be mapped to an object of type `CustomPojo`. That `Object` object is actually a `Map` too. So you need to iterate again over those maps and create the `CustomPojo` objects yourself in order to achieve a `Map<String, CustomPojo>`.

Please also see my answer from the following post:

- [How to read/update values stored inside a map which is then inside of an array in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649314/how-to-read-update-values-stored-inside-a-map-which-is-then-inside-of-an-array-i/55649917#55649917)

Comment: Oh, you're right. But is there possible to insert array of objects inside documents? as we did in a realtimedatabase node?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but is not possible to read them back as an array of objects, unless you to the same approach, as explained in my answer from the linked post.